# what is the pincode when pairing a JBL Charge 2+?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth-speaker

So, I have `Xubuntu 14.04.4` on an old `Toshiba Lifebook S` laptop. 
I have been using (so far) `Blueman Device Manager 1.23` to manage connection and, honestly, I would not be able to report successful connections.

My `GT-I9195` seemingly connects, but no way I manage to browse its filesystem or send a file (yet - I do accept it when prompted...).
So there's a tough chance the problem lies with my hardware or with Blueman. Anyway, I got this: I have just purchased a bluetooth stereo speaker JBL Charge 2+. My laptop 'sees' it but when pairing asks for a pin code. Neither "0000" nor "1234" work.

I could find absolutely nothing on this issue on the net - posts on this forum about JBL Charge 2 do not seem to apply, they are quite old, and anyway they have remain unanswered.

Thanks for your help - or thanks for trying.

Comment: have you had any success on `14.04` ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I do appreciate your answers. Truth is I neglected this thread - I cannot report any success on this. Actually I gave up some time ago, when I just ditched the old Toshiba Lifebook S. It worked OK now with my new, 64-bit, while using Xenial.Just moved to Bionic and did not test yet.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [quick start guide](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/786485/Jbl-Charge.html?page=2#manual) the code is 0000, so you must have other problems with your connection.

Edit - that link appears to be for a Charge, [this link](https://www.manualsearcher.com/jbl/charge-2/manual) for the Charge 2 does not show any code at all.

Edit 2 - neither does [this manual](http://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/114603.pdf) for the Charge 2+.

Comment: Thanks, OM. I am going to look into the Charge 2+ manual anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pin code. All you have to do is update your Bluetooth drivers.

Device manager > Bluetooth > Update drivers

I had this stupid pin problem, and these steps were enough to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 the automatic code selections works after some tries. Not super solid, but after turning BT off and on again i could finally select it in the sound settings as output. In the sound settings i did need to switch the mode to "A2DP sink" from the preconfigured "HSP/HFP". As said not completely hasslefree but i now got the beats rocking with the combination of Thinkpad x230's integrated Bluetooth and a JBCL Charge 2+ :)

Comment: I have tried on an old Samsung NC10 with Feather Linux (which should be based on Ubuntu), Blueman Device Mgr again. Well I started believing that the problem should be with Blueman. Btw, on the NC10 the pin "0000" is successful, yet no sound out (yes, I did set also the audio sink option). I'll try to see what happens doing as you suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is a pain but make sure Pulseaudio is installed with

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Then make sure pulseaudio is started. I typed pulse in the box on the Start menu.

Then try to connect. You may have to fiddle in the pulse volume control to output from the Charge 2+ instead of pc speakers.